# How to make a string compare work in CloudBuild?

Tags: sh, google-cloud-build

I have a simple string test in my GCP *CloudBuild* step, but it never works. The step looks like this

```
steps:

- id: 'branch name'
  name: 'alpine'
  entrypoint: 'sh'  
  args: 
  - '-c'
  - | 
      export ENV=$BRANCH_NAME
      if [ $ENV = "master" ]; then
         export ENV="test-dev"
      fi
      echo "***********************"
      echo "$BRANCH_NAME"
      echo "$ENV"
      echo "***********************"
```

*CloudBuild* always reports this as `sh: master: unknown operand`. It's a literal, obviously.
I put the same code into a little `sh` script and it ran fine as long as I set a value for `BRANCH_NAME`. *CloudBuild* definitely supplies a value for `BRANCH_NAME` and it shows up in the `echo "$BRANCH_NAME"` while the `echo "$ENV"` is always empty.

Is there a way to make this string compare work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use linux [env var and not substitution variables (or predefined variables), you have to escape the `$` with another one](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values#using_user-defined_substitutions)

```
steps:

- id: 'branch name'
  name: 'alpine'
  entrypoint: 'sh'  
  args: 
  - '-c'
  - | 
      export ENV=$BRANCH_NAME
      if [ $$ENV = "master" ]; then
         export ENV="test-dev"
      fi
      echo "***********************"
      echo "$BRANCH_NAME"
      echo "$$ENV"
      echo "***********************"
```